# Exec reference libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference, portable-executable

I have an application I made with a reference to [an external library](http://watin.org/). I need to send it over to a computer which does not have Visual Studio and execute it, so I figured I'd compile the whole thing and send the executable. The problem is, although on my computer the solution runs just fine (even if I run just the exec file), on his computer it says the external library is not linked when he tries to execute it - it instantly crashes.

How can I send an exec file which will work even if he does not have the library installed? Could it have something to do with DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to provide the referenced dlls as well, otherwise it won't work.
You can use the Visual studio feature, when you find the reference in Solution explorer, click on your nonstandard references and choose "Copy local" property on them. Then you'll have corresponding referenced dlls in your bin/debug folders when you build and publish your projects.

Every time you have external dependencies that aren't a standard part of .NET framework, you have to include those along your other files.

Comment: I found the copy local property, what should i do with it? (It's currently set to "true") and once I have the DLL files, do i send them along with the executable, or does it work on it's own?

Comment: @A.Abramov, when you set Copy Local to True, those references will be copied to your bin or debug folders along .exe file. However, you have to ship these files to your clients as well. Copy Local is useful to group all the necessary files "under one roof". If you don't do it, you have to copy corresponding dlls yourself. Without it the software works locally, because it can find those references in your local pc, but your clients need to have those files as well if they wish to run it.

Comment: great answer, I understand everything (:
Just one last thing before I give you the checkmark you deserve - Is there any way to do this programatically?

Comment: @A.Abramov, well, I guess you could do it programatically, but it would get unnecessary complicated. This way it's just a matter of checking one checkmark in your Visual studio. You don't have to do this for every reference. Do it just for those 3rd party libraries you use. Other option would be setting up an installer where you'll specify required files and it will create an installer package for you, but that depends on your requirements etc. Easiest way obviously is just to copy those dlls manually to the same directory and you're good to go.